# Frozen adding a new row to a grid (wxwidgets)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, wxwidgets

this is my first project using wxWidgets and maybe this is the typical mistake of a begginer but I cannot find the error.The program is just a chat using the TeamSpeak SDK, so that it's very simple. As you can guest, I have a Grid to show the messages but the problem is that sometimes I cannot add a new row. The program is complete frozen when it happens without any exception even when I'm debugging, the callStack is completly empty on Visual Studio 2013 and I cannot understand why this happens because, if I add a row at the constructor class, the row is added without any problem.

What I'm doing is to adapt the program into the MVC pattern because the program previously worked but the guy programed it before, didn't do it following this pattern, but it worked!

So, this is the header GUI class,

```
#pragma once
#ifdef __BORLANDC__
#pragma hdrstop
#endif
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/frame.h>
#else
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#endif
#include "../Data/config.h"
#include "../lib/ClientTS.h"
#include "../data/Session.h"
#include "../data/Message.h"
#include "FrmMailSending.h"
#include "FrmSettingMail.h"
#include "AudioWizard.h"
#include "NationList.h"
#include "LoginWarnings.h"
#include "../ArchiveLog.h"
#include "FrmSaveChat.h"
#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/timer.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h>
#include <wx/richtext/richtextctrl.h>
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
#include <wx/button.h>
#include <wx/grid.h>
#include "../GlobalVariables.h"
#include "../translateController/translateController.h"
#include "../translateController/translateVariable.h"
#include <list>
//#include "../lib/Observer.h"
#define MENU_ESCI 1800
#define MENU_OPZIONI 1801
#define MENU_SPEECH 1802
class ClientTsFrm : public wxFrame
{
private:
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
    double conta;
    void askForSaving();
    void WxButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void btnsendClick(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void txtchatClick(wxRichTextEvent& event);
    void txtchatEnter(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnTimerTimeout(wxTimerEvent& event);
    void WxTimer1Timer(wxTimerEvent& event);
    void txtmsgEnter(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void RefreshChat();
    void btnspeechClick(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void ClientTsFrmActivate(wxActivateEvent& event);
    void WxButton2Click(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void WxTimer2Timer(wxTimerEvent& event);
    void gridchatCellLeftClick(wxGridEvent& event);
    void Debug(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void Wizard(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void WxBitmapButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void Mail(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void SettingMail(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void Save(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event);
public:
    // virtual void Notify(Observee* observee);
    ClientTsFrm(LoginWarnings *warn, wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id = 1, const wxString &title = wxT("TeamTranslate"),
        const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
        long style = wxCAPTION | wxSYSTEM_MENU | wxCLOSE_BOX | wxRESIZE_BORDER);
    virtual ~ClientTsFrm(){};
    /*ClientTsFrm(const ClientTsFrm &o)
    {
    &this = &o;
    }*/
    void updatePanelMsg();
    void didit(){
        cout << "i did it";
    }
private:
    unsigned int curRow; //Initialize Row index
    unsigned int curCol; //Initialize Column index
    Session* session;
    ConfigPTR config;
    NationList *nations;
    int REFRESHTIMER = 0;
    uint64 _sclogID;
    wxTimer *WxTimer2;
    wxTimer *WxTimer1;
    wxButton *btnspeech;
    wxRichTextCtrl *txtclient;
    wxTextCtrl *txtlingua;
    wxStaticText *lbllingua;
    wxStaticText *lblnick;
    wxTextCtrl *txtnick;
    wxRichTextCtrl *txtchat;
    wxButton *btnsend;
    wxTextCtrl *txtmsg;
    wxGrid *gridchat;
    wxGrid *gridclient;
    wxBoxSizer *sizer;
    wxGridSizer *gridsizer;
    wxMenuBar *WxMenuBar1;
    wxMenu *ID_MNU_FILE_1001_Mnu_Obj;
    wxMenu *ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj;
    wxBitmapButton *WxBitmapButton1;
    /////
    ClientTS clientts;
    COLORE *colors;
    enum
    {
        ////GUI Enum Control ID Start
        ID_GRIDCLIENT = 1034,
        ID_GRIDCHAT = 1033,
        ID_WXTIMER2 = 1014,
        ID_WXTIMER1 = 1006,
        ID_WXBUTTON3 = 1013,
        ID_WXRICHTEXTCTRL1 = 1012,
        ID_WXEDIT2 = 1011,
        ID_WXSTATICTEXT2 = 1010,
        ID_WXSTATICTEXT1 = 1009,
        ID_WXEDIT1 = 1008,
        ID_WXRICHTEXTCTRL2 = 1005,
        ID_WXBUTTON2 = 1004,
        ID_WXEDIT3 = 1003,
        ID_WXBUTTON1 = 1001,
        ID_MNU_FILE_1001 = 1111,
        ID_MNU_SAVE_1002 = 1118,
        ID_MNU_MAIL_1004 = 1117,
        ID_MNU_SETTINGMAIL_1007 = 1119,
        ID_MNU_ESCI_1003 = 1113,
        ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004 = 1114,
        ID_MNU_AUDIO_1005 = 1115,
        ID_MNU_SPEECH_1006 = 1116,
        ID_WXBITMAPBUTTON1 = 1024,
        ////GUI Enum Control ID End
        ID_DUMMY_VALUE_ //don't remove this value unless you have other enum values
    };
};
class MyGridCellRenderer : public wxGridCellStringRenderer
{
private:
    wxBitmap* bitmap;
public:
    virtual void Draw(wxGrid& grid,
        wxGridCellAttr& attr,
        wxDC& dc,
        const wxRect& rect,
        int row, int col,
        bool isSelected);
    void setPicture(wxString);
    MyGridCellRenderer(wxString name)
    {
        if (name == "") bitmap = new wxBitmap(NULL);
        else bitmap = new wxBitmap(name, wxBITMAP_TYPE_BMP);
    }
};
```

ClientTsFrm.cpp code :

```
#include "ClientTsFrm.h"

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(ClientTsFrm, wxFrame)

EVT_CLOSE(ClientTsFrm::OnClose)
EVT_TIMER(ID_WXTIMER2, ClientTsFrm::WxTimer2Timer)
EVT_TIMER(ID_WXTIMER1, ClientTsFrm::WxTimer1Timer)
EVT_BUTTON(ID_WXBITMAPBUTTON1, ClientTsFrm::WxBitmapButton1Click)
EVT_BUTTON(ID_WXBUTTON2, ClientTsFrm::btnsendClick)
EVT_TEXT_ENTER(ID_WXEDIT3, ClientTsFrm::txtmsgEnter)
EVT_BUTTON(ID_WXBUTTON1, ClientTsFrm::WxButton1Click)
EVT_MENU(ID_MNU_MAIL_1004, ClientTsFrm::Mail)
EVT_MENU(ID_MNU_SETTINGMAIL_1007, ClientTsFrm::SettingMail)
EVT_MENU(ID_MNU_SAVE_1002, ClientTsFrm::Save)
EVT_MENU(ID_MNU_ESCI_1003, ClientTsFrm::Debug)
EVT_MENU(ID_MNU_AUDIO_1005, ClientTsFrm::Wizard)
EVT_MENU(ID_MNU_SPEECH_1006, ClientTsFrm::btnspeechClick)
EVT_GRID_CELL_LEFT_CLICK(ClientTsFrm::gridchatCellLeftClick)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
ClientTsFrm::ClientTsFrm(LoginWarnings*warnings, wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString &title, const wxPoint &position, const wxSize& size, long style)
: wxFrame(parent, id, title, position, size, style)
{
    this->nations = new NationList();
    //registerObserver<ClientTsFrm>(&ClientTsFrm::notify, *this);
    this->nations->ReadFromFile("..\\conf\\locales_code.txt");
    session = Session::Instance();
    config = session->getConfig();
    //clientts.setCBClientTSMSG(notify);
    //clientts = new ClientTS;
    //session->registerObserver<ClientTsFrm>(*this);
    colors = (COLORE*)malloc(10 * sizeof(COLORE));
    session->registerObserver(EventTS::MSG_RCV, &notifyMSG, this);//.AddObserver(this);
    //registercb(*this); // register itself into clientTs "class" in order to be notified about any change
    curRow = 0; //Initialize Row index
    curCol = 0;
    if (warnings->IsHostnameEmpty())
        ts3client_logMessage("Hostname field is empty", LogLevel_WARNING, "Gui", _sclogID);
    if (warnings->IsNicknameEmpty())
        ts3client_logMessage("Nickname field is empty", LogLevel_WARNING, "Gui", _sclogID);
    //TODO Completare la traduzione di ClientTsFrm usando le variabile statica labels
    clientts.setFlagSave(true);
    FILE * record;
    FILE * translate;
    if (record = fopen("recorded.wav", "r"))
    {
        remove("");
        fclose(record);
    }
    if (translate = fopen("translate.txt", "r"))
    {
        remove("");
        fclose(translate);
    }
    gridchat = new wxGrid(this, ID_GRIDCHAT, wxPoint(211, 72), wxSize(722, 350));
    gridchat->CreateGrid(0, 2, wxGrid::wxGridSelectCells);
    gridchat->SetColLabelValue(0, wxString::FromUTF8(labels.gridMessage.c_str()));
    gridchat->SetColLabelValue(1, "Play");
    gridchat->SetRowSize(curRow + 1, 40);
    gridchat->SetColSize(curCol, 610);
    gridchat->SetColSize(curCol + 1, 30);
    /*gridchat->SetCellValue(messaggio, curRow, 0);
    gridchat->SetCellRenderer(curRow++, 1, new MyGridCellRenderer(L"../res/play.bmp"));
    gridchat->AutoSizeRow(curRow - 1, true);
    gridchat->SetColSize(curCol + 1, 30);*/
    WxTimer2 = new wxTimer();
    WxTimer2->SetOwner(this, ID_WXTIMER2);
    WxTimer2->Start(200);
    WxTimer1 = new wxTimer();
    WxTimer1->SetOwner(this, ID_WXTIMER1);
    WxTimer1->Start(200);
    txtclient = new wxRichTextCtrl(this, ID_WXRICHTEXTCTRL1, _(""), wxPoint(10, 75), wxSize(184, 155), wxRE_READONLY, wxDefaultValidator, _("txtclient"));
    txtclient->SetMaxLength(0);
    txtclient->SetFocus();
    txtclient->SetInsertionPointEnd();
    txtclient->SetFont(wxFont(8, wxSWISS, wxNORMAL, wxNORMAL, false));
    /*txtlingua shows the language chosen*/
    txtlingua = new wxTextCtrl(this, ID_WXEDIT2, _(""), wxPoint(367, 20), wxSize(103, 20), wxTE_READONLY, wxDefaultValidator, _("txtlingua"));
    txtlingua->SetFont(wxFont(8, wxSWISS, wxNORMAL, wxNORMAL, false));
    lbllingua = new wxStaticText(this, ID_WXSTATICTEXT2, _(wxString::FromUTF8(labels.language.append(":").c_str())), wxPoint(299, 20), wxDefaultSize, 0, _("lbllingua"));
    lbllingua->SetFont(wxFont(8, wxSWISS, wxNORMAL, wxNORMAL, false));
    lblnick = new wxStaticText(this, ID_WXSTATICTEXT1, _("Nickname:"), wxPoint(14, 20), wxDefaultSize, 0, _("lblnick"));
    lblnick->SetFont(wxFont(8, wxSWISS, wxNORMAL, wxNORMAL, false));
    /*txtnick shows the name chosen*/
    txtnick = new wxTextCtrl(this, ID_WXEDIT1, _(""), wxPoint(91, 20), wxSize(102, 20), wxTE_READONLY, wxDefaultValidator, _("txtnick"));
    txtnick->SetFont(wxFont(8, wxSWISS, wxNORMAL, wxNORMAL, false));
    /* btnsend: botton which sends the message typed */
    btnsend = new wxButton(this, ID_WXBUTTON2, _(wxString::FromUTF8(labels.send.c_str())), wxPoint(830, 450), wxSize(103, 48), 0, wxDefaultValidator, _("btnsend"));
    btnsend->SetFont(wxFont(8, wxSWISS, wxNORMAL, wxNORMAL, false));
    /* Txtmsg: box where you can type a message*/
    txtmsg = new wxTextCtrl(this, ID_WXEDIT3, _(""), wxPoint(211, 450), wxSize(570, 45), wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER, wxDefaultValidator, _("txtmsg"));
    txtmsg->SetFont(wxFont(8, wxSWISS, wxNORMAL, wxNORMAL, false));
    txtmsg->SetFocus();
    wxBitmap WxBitmapButton1_BITMAP(NULL);
    WxBitmapButton1 = new wxBitmapButton(this, ID_WXBITMAPBUTTON1, WxBitmapButton1_BITMAP, wxPoint(211 + 570, 450), wxSize(50, 45), wxBU_AUTODRAW, wxDefaultValidator, _("WxBitmapButton1"));
    string enableSTTService = "";
    enableSTTService.append(labels.enable);
    enableSTTService.append(" SpeechToText Service");
    WxBitmapButton1->SetToolTip(_(enableSTTService));
    WxMenuBar1 = new wxMenuBar();
    ID_MNU_FILE_1001_Mnu_Obj = new wxMenu();
    ID_MNU_FILE_1001_Mnu_Obj->Append(ID_MNU_SAVE_1002, labels.saveMenu, _(""), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    ID_MNU_FILE_1001_Mnu_Obj->Append(ID_MNU_MAIL_1004, labels.mailMenu, _(""), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    ID_MNU_FILE_1001_Mnu_Obj->Append(ID_MNU_ESCI_1003, labels.exitMenu, _(""), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    WxMenuBar1->Append(ID_MNU_FILE_1001_Mnu_Obj, _("File"));
    ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj = new wxMenu();
    ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj->Append(ID_MNU_SETTINGMAIL_1007, labels.emailSetting, _(""), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj->Append(ID_MNU_AUDIO_1005, labels.audioMenu, _(""), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj->AppendCheckItem(ID_MNU_SPEECH_1006, _(enableSTTService), _(""));
    WxMenuBar1->Append(ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj, labels.options);
    SetMenuBar(WxMenuBar1);
    SetTitle(_("TeamTranslate"));
    SetIcon(wxNullIcon);
    SetSize(8, 8, 1024, 600);
    Center();
#if wxUSE_LIBPNG
    wxImage::AddHandler(new wxPNGHandler);
#endif
#if wxUSE_LIBJPEG
    wxImage::AddHandler(new wxJPEGHandler);
#endif
#if wxUSE_GIF
    wxImage::AddHandler(new wxGIFHandler);
#endif
    ////GUI Items Creation End
    conta = 10.0;
    FILE *api;
    /*FILE*config;
    if (config = fopen("..\\bin\\conf\\config.txt", "r"))
    {
    fscanf(config, "%s", &SERVER_ADDRESS);
    fscanf(config, "%s", &NICK);
    fscanf(config, "%d", &cmbel);
    fscanf(config, "%s", &CURRENT_LANG);
    fscanf(config, "%s", &SERVICE);
    fclose(config);
    }
    if (api = fopen("..\\bin\\conf\\GOOGLE.txt", "r"))
    {
    char API[200];
    fscanf(api, "%s", API);
    session->setGoogleAPIKey(API);
    fclose(api);
    }
    */
    txtnick->AppendText(config->getNick());
    txtlingua->AppendText(config->getLanguage());
    HANDLE myHandle = CreateThread(0, 0, clientts.ClientStart, NULL, 0, &myThreadID);
    HANDLE myHandle2 = CreateThread(0, 0, clientts.TTS_THREAD, NULL, 0, &myThreadID2);
    HANDLE myHandle3 = CreateThread(0, 0, clientts.STT_THREAD, NULL, 0, &myThreadID4);
    /*HANDLE myHandle4 = CreateThread(0, 0, CTRL_STT, NULL, 0, &myThreadID4);*/
    clientts.SetupColor(colors);
    /*char *str = this->nations->Search(CURRENT_LANG, APICODE);
    wchar_t* wString = new wchar_t[4096];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, -1, wString, 4096);
    MessageBox(NULL, wString, L"Test print handler", MB_OK);*/
}
void MyGridCellRenderer::Draw(wxGrid& grid, wxGridCellAttr& attr, wxDC& dc, const wxRect& rect, int row, int col, bool isSelected)
{
    wxGridCellStringRenderer::Draw(grid, attr, dc, rect, row, col, isSelected);
    dc.DrawBitmap(*bitmap, 0, 0, 0);
    dc.DrawBitmap(*bitmap, rect.x + 6, rect.y + 4);
}
void MyGridCellRenderer::setPicture(wxString name)
{
    return;
}
void ClientTsFrm::gridchatCellLeftClick(wxGridEvent& event)
{
    list<MESSAGE>::iterator iter;
    iter = diary.begin();
    wxString strSpeak;
    for (int i = 0; i < event.GetRow(); i++) iter++; //point to the selected message in the grid
    wxToolTip * tooltip = new wxToolTip((*iter).msgold);
    tooltip->SetAutoPop(10000);
    tooltip->SetMaxWidth(200);
    strSpeak = wxString::FromAscii(strtok((char*)gridchat->GetCellValue(event.GetRow(), 0).mb_str().data(), ")"));
    strSpeak = wxString::FromAscii(strtok(NULL, ":"));
    if (event.GetCol() == 1) { session->tts_flag = true; }
    if (event.GetCol() == 0) { gridchat->GetGridWindow()->SetToolTip(tooltip); }
}
void ClientTsFrm::OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event)
{
    askForSaving();
    clientts.disconnect();
    Sleep(300);
    Destroy();
}
/*Refresh chat for new message or new clients*/
void ClientTsFrm::RefreshChat()
{
    int i = 0;
    UserListPTR luser = Session::Instance()->getListUser();
    wxUniChar ch = ':';
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm tstruct;
    char buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%X", &tstruct);
    clientts.showClients(DEFAULT_VIRTUAL_SERVER);
    txtclient->Clear(); //Clear client window
    for (auto it = luser->cbegin(); it != luser->cend(); ++it)
    {
        UserPTR uptr = *it;
        if (uptr->getName() != "") //if there is a client name
        {
            if (uptr->getSpeak() == 0 && uptr->getWrite() == 0) //gridclient->SetCellRenderer(i, 2, new MyGridCellRenderer(L""));
                txtclient->BeginTextColour(wxColour(colors[i].red, colors[i].green, colors[i].blue));
            if (uptr->getSpeak() == 1) //if this client is speaking show microphone
            {
                wxString naz = this->nations->Search(uptr->getLang().ToStdString(), COUNTRY);
                wxBitmap bitmap = wxBitmap();
                bitmap.LoadFile("..\\res\\" + naz + ".png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
                txtclient->WriteImage(bitmap);
                txtclient->WriteText(uptr->getName() + "\t");
                //if (person[i].lang == "Italian") {
                //txtclient->WriteImage(wxBitmap(italy_xpm));
                //}
                //if (strncmp(person[i].lang,"English",7)==0) { /*gridclient->SetCellRenderer(i, 1, new MyGridCellRenderer(L"../res/usa.bmp"));*/ txtclient->WriteImage(wxBitmap(usa_xpm)); }
                //if (person[i].lang == "Portuguese") { /*gridclient->SetCellRenderer(i, 1, new MyGridCellRenderer(L"../res/brasil.bmp"));*/ txtclient->WriteImage(wxBitmap(brasil_xpm)); }
                txtclient->WriteText("\t");
                txtclient->WriteImage(wxBitmap(microphone_xpm));
            }
            else if (uptr->getSpeak() == 0) //if this client is writing show keayboard
            {
                wxString naz = this->nations->Search(uptr->getLang().ToStdString(), COUNTRY);
                wxBitmap bitmap = wxBitmap();
                bitmap.LoadFile("..\\res\\" + naz + ".png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
                txtclient->WriteImage(bitmap);
                /*gridclient->SetCellTextColour(wxColour(colors[i].red, colors[i].green, colors[i].blue), i, 0);
                gridclient->SetCellValue(i, 0, person[i].name);*/
                txtclient->WriteText(uptr->getName() + "\t");
                //if (person[i].lang == "Italian") { /*gridclient->SetCellRenderer(i, 1, new MyGridCellRenderer(L"../res/.bmp"));*/ txtclient->WriteImage(wxBitmap(italy_xpm)); }
                //if (strncmp(person[i].lang, "English", 7) == 0) { /*gridclient->SetCellRenderer(i, 1, new MyGridCellRenderer(L"../res/usa.bmp")); */txtclient->WriteImage(wxBitmap(usa_xpm)); }
                //if (person[i].lang == "Portuguese") { /*gridclient->SetCellRenderer(i, 1, new MyGridCellRenderer(L"../res/brasil.bmp"));*/ txtclient->WriteImage(wxBitmap(brasil_xpm)); }
                if (uptr->getWrite() == 1)
                {
                    txtclient->WriteText("\t");
                    txtclient->WriteImage(wxBitmap(keyboard_xpm));
                    //gridclient->SetCellRenderer(i, 2, new MyGridCellRenderer(L"../res/keyboard.bmp"));
                }
            }
            txtclient->EndTextColour();
            txtclient->Newline();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
/*
* WxButton1Click
*/
void ClientTsFrm::WxButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
}
/*
* btnsendClick
*/
void ClientTsFrm::btnsendClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    txtmsg->DiscardEdits(); //Clear buffer of textbox
    clientts.sendMessage(&txtmsg->GetValue());
    txtmsg->Clear();
}
/*
* WxTimer1Timer
*/
void ClientTsFrm::WxTimer1Timer(wxTimerEvent& event)
{
    RefreshChat();
}
/*
* txtmsgEnter
*/
void ClientTsFrm::txtmsgEnter(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    btnsendClick(event);
}
/*
* btnspeechClick
*/
void ClientTsFrm::btnspeechClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    session->setautomatic_stt_flag(!session->getautomatic_stt_flag());
    if (session->getautomatic_stt_flag() == false)
    {
        string stdisabled = "";
        stdisabled.append(labels.enable);
        stdisabled.append(" Speech to text");
        ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj->SetLabel(ID_MNU_SPEECH_1006, wxString::FromUTF8(stdisabled.c_str()));
        ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj->Check(ID_MNU_SPEECH_1006, false);
        WxBitmapButton1->Enable(true);
    }
    else
    {
        string stenabled = "";
        stenabled.append(labels.disable);
        stenabled.append(" Speech to text");
        ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj->SetLabel(ID_MNU_SPEECH_1006, wxString::FromUTF8(stenabled.c_str()));
        ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj->Check(ID_MNU_SPEECH_1006, true);
        WxBitmapButton1->Enable(false);
    }
}
/*
* WxTimer2Timer
*/
void ClientTsFrm::WxTimer2Timer(wxTimerEvent& event)
{
    UserListPTR luser = Session::Instance()->getListUser();
    clientts.setVadLevel(DEFAULT_VIRTUAL_SERVER);
    if (txtmsg->IsModified()) session->setwrite_flag(true);
    int i;
    for (auto it = luser->cbegin(); it != luser->cend(); ++it)
    {
        if ((*it)->getName() == config->getNick())
        {
            if ((*it)->getWrite() == 0 && session->getwrite_flag())
            {
                wxString scrive_msg = "\n" + wxString::FromAscii(config->getLanguage()) + "\n" + "write1";
                ts3client_requestSendChannelTextMsg(DEFAULT_VIRTUAL_SERVER, scrive_msg, (uint64)1, NULL);
            }
        }
    }
}
void ClientTsFrm::Debug(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    askForSaving();
    clientts.disconnect();
    Sleep(300);
    Destroy();
}
void ClientTsFrm::Wizard(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    // insert your code here
    AudioWizard* dialog = new AudioWizard(NULL);
    dialog->Show(true);
}
void ClientTsFrm::WxBitmapButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    session->settasto_stt_flag(!session->gettasto_stt_flag());
    if (session->gettasto_stt_flag() == false)
    {
        ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj->Enable(ID_MNU_SPEECH_1006, true);
        WxBitmapButton1->SetBitmap(NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        session->setsound_flag(true);
        clientts.getIAudioRecorder()->startRecordingBufferedAudio();
        WxBitmapButton1->SetBitmap(microphone_xpm);
        ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj->Enable(ID_MNU_SPEECH_1006, false);
    }
}
void ClientTsFrm::Mail(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    FrmMailSending *frame = new FrmMailSending(NULL);
    frame->ShowModal();
}
void ClientTsFrm::SettingMail(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    FrmSettingMail *frame2 = new FrmSettingMail(NULL);
    frame2->ShowModal();
}
void ClientTsFrm::Save(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    askForSaving();
}
void ClientTsFrm::askForSaving(){
    if (!clientts.getFlagSave()){
        wxMessageDialog *dial = new wxMessageDialog(NULL, labels.saveMessage, labels.saveMenu, wxYES_NO | wxYES_DEFAULT | wxICON_QUESTION);
        dial->SetYesNoLabels(_(labels.yes), _(labels.no));
        int result = dial->ShowModal();
        if (result == wxID_YES)
        {
            FrmSaveChat *frame = new FrmSaveChat(NULL);
            result = frame->ShowModal();
            if (result == wxID_YES){
                clientts.setFlagSave(true); // chat saved
                wxMessageBox(labels.saveSuccess);
            }
        }
        else
            // first the user has decided to save the chat session, then he has changed his decision
            clientts.setFlagSave(false); // chat not saved
    }
    else
        wxMessageBox(labels.noSave);
}
void ClientTsFrm::updatePanelMsg(){
    /****
    * add new message to chat grid
    * ***/
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm tstruct;
    char buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%X", &tstruct);
    UserListPTR luser = Session::Instance()->getListUser();
    MessageQueuePTR lptr = Session::Instance()->getMessageQueue();
    for (auto itmsg = lptr->cbegin(); itmsg != lptr->cend(); ++itmsg)
    {
        if (wxString::FromUTF8((*itmsg)->getMSG()) == ">" || wxString::FromUTF8((*itmsg)->getMSG()) == "</html>" || wxString::FromUTF8((*itmsg)->getMSG())[0] == '<' || wxString::FromUTF8((*itmsg)->getMSG())[0] == '>')
            return;
        gridchat->Scroll(curRow + 20, curCol + 20);
        gridchat->AppendRows(1, true); //Add a new message row
        wxString messaggio = wxString::FromUTF8((*itmsg)->getFrom()) + "(" + buf + "): " + wxString::FromUTF8((*itmsg)->getMSG());
        gridchat->SetCellValue(messaggio, curRow, 0);
        gridchat->SetCellRenderer(curRow++, 1, new MyGridCellRenderer(L"../res/play.bmp"));
        gridchat->AutoSizeRow(curRow - 1, true);
        gridchat->SetColSize(curCol + 1, 30);
    }
    /*
    //if (strGlobale != "" && StringTranslate != oldStringTranslate/* strGlobale!=oldstrGlobale && StringTranslate != "" * /)
    if (wxString::FromAscii(clientts.LANG_MSG_SRC) == ">" || wxString::FromAscii(clientts.LANG_MSG_SRC) == "</html>" || clientts.LANG_MSG_SRC[0] == '<' || clientts.LANG_MSG_SRC[0] == '>')
    return;
    gridchat->AppendRows(1, true); //Add a new message row
    if (strNick == config->getNick())
    {
    wxString messaggio = wxString::FromUTF8((*itmsg)->getFrom()) + "(" + buf + "): " + wxString::FromUTF8((*itmsg)->getMSG());
    // gridchat->SetCellValue(messaggio, Session::Session::curRow, 0);
    gridchat->SetCellRenderer(curRow++, 1, new MyGridCellRenderer(L"../res/play.bmp"));
    gridchat->AutoSizeRow(curRow - 1, true);
    gridchat->SetColSize(curCol + 1, 30);
    }
    else
    {
    for (auto it = luser->cbegin(); it != luser->cend(); ++it)
    {
    /*if (wxString::FromUTF8((*itmsg)->getFrom()) == (*it)->getName() && (*it)->getUsed() == 1)
    {* /
    wxString messaggio = wxString::FromUTF8((*itmsg)->getFrom()) + "(" + buf + "): " + wxString::FromUTF8((*itmsg)->getMSG());
    gridchat->SetCellTextColour(curRow, 0, wxColour(colors[(*it)->getColor()].red, colors[(*it)->getColor()].green, colors[(*it)->getColor()].blue));
    gridchat->SetCellValue(messaggio, curRow, 0);
    gridchat->SetRowSize(curRow, 40);
    gridchat->SetColSize(curCol, 578);
    gridchat->SetColSize(curCol + 1, 60);
    gridchat->SetCellRenderer(curRow++, 1, new MyGridCellRenderer(L"../res/play.bmp"));
    // }
    }
    }
    oldStringTranslate = StringTranslate;
    oldstrGlobale = strGlobale;
    strGlobale = "";
    }
    /*else
    {
    if (count_client == 0 && REFRESHTIMER > 50) //ho sostituito empty_room e messo il timer
    {
    ts3client_logMessage("No such clients found", LogLevel_ERROR, "Channel", _sclogID);
    REFRESHTIMER = 0;
    }
    }
```

The program is frozed when I'm debugging, on this line:

gridchat->AppendRows(1, true); //Add a new message row

How is it possible ? how can I fix it ? I'm using exwidgets 2.9.3 version
Thank you very much for your time.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is indeed impossible, you must be able to break into the program in the debugger. Are you sure the debugger is not just busy, e.g. downloading the symbols (which can take a long time)?

Comment: Also, on an unrelated subject, do use wxWidgets 3.0.2 and not 2.9.x, there is no possible good reason to be using the latter for any new code.

Comment: Thanks @VZ, However I updated the version and it still happens. But I chenged by a wxListCtrl and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Given the error behaviour, chances are that the call to AppendRows triggers an event that calls updatePanelMsg() again. So you get an infinite stack of calls to the function, which breaks the debugger as well as your program.

If this is the case, you could add a Boolean flag in ClientTsFrm, signalling if there is already a call to updatePanelMsg on the stack.

On a unrelated note, at present all the "private" members of your class are actually only protected, because of the DECLARE EVENT TABLE macro.